# Use XLSX.js with base64

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript

Tried doing

```
var work = XLSX.readFile("D:\\sched.xls"); //var XLSX = <XLSX>require('xlsx');
```

But I believe I am having the issues described in this issue.
https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js/issues/11

EDIT BEGIN
Found that I was actually using a different library then the one that I found the issue listed with.
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/135
EDIT END

The workaround is "read file with base64 encoding, then passing it to xlsx does it."

```
var fileRead = fs.readFileSync("D:\\sched.xls");
var base64 = fileRead.toString('base64');

//The workaround seems to be talking about some xlsx function?
//even .read doesn't seem to be thing based on my typescript binding.
var workbook = XLSX.read(base64); //to use read switch:
//                                 var XLSX = <XLSX>require('xlsx');
//                                 var XLSX = require('xlsx')
```

So I'm pretty sure I have read in the file using base64 encoding how do I pass that into xlsx.js

Comment: How does the complete use case look like? You are trying to use node.js to load Excel file and..? BTW: **xls and xlsx are completely different file formats**, [xls is weird binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615597(v=office.14).aspx), [xlsx is zipped xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: When you have access to a java runtime, with [POI from Apache](http://poi.apache.org/) you could convert XLS to XLSX (when the file not include to complex diagrams or formulas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an Excel reader that supports ".xls" format. For example, [excel-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/excel-parser) library supports both ".xls" and ".xlsx" formats.

I don't know what library you are using, but given it is called `XLSX`, I expect it can only parse the modern ".xlsx" format and not the older ".xls" format (and your file has an ".xls" extension).

```
var excelParser = require('excel-parser');

excelParser.worksheets({
    inFile: 'D:\\sched.xls'
}, function(err, worksheets){
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

    console.log(worksheets);
});
```

Would give you the output in a format such as this:

```
[
  ['ID', 'Name', 'Location'],
  ['1757491', 'Travis', 'Philadelphia'],
  ['75525', 'Steve', 'UK']
]
```

Comment: Thanks the author of the library I was using actually has another library that can handle both https://www.npmjs.org/package/j as well.